# Detect one of multiple objects with OpenCV in one pass

Tags: opencv

I have no experience in OpenCV and its words like SIFT, SURF etc. are scary. So excuse me for the lame question.

**Is OpenCV able to find one of multiple images in some picture in a single pass?**

The main value is **speed**.

Let's say there is an HD camera on a fast moving object that gets **1920x1080** picture. The object that drives along path with road signs, banners and maybe some LED info signs. So this **fast moving object should not miss any of the road signs**.

My concern is that if OpenCV rescans camera shot for each sign, it will take `shot_time + n*scan_time` to detect all possible road signs. With increased amount of signs, the `n*scan_time` operation (which is essentially O(n)) may take so long that the fast moving object may miss the next sign.

So is there a way in OpenCV to try to find **one** of different images during single scan? If yes, that is the limit that it can handle and what is the O() ratio?

A similar question. Is there a way in OpenCV to try to find **many** different images during single pass?

Pseudocode:

```
events = [
    'stop.png',
    'warning.png',
    'crossing_deer.png'
]

result = OpenCV.scan(camera_shot, events)

if 'stop.png' in result:
    handle_stop()
if 'warning.png' in result:
    awake_operator()
if 'crossing_deer.png' in result:
    prepare_for_impact()
    notify_wwf(deer=-1)
```

Comment: 1. you dont want to `find multiple images` but you want to detect (one of) multiple objects! That's a very different thing than searching for a specific image (from which you might know exactly´the size how each pixel looks like). 2. It is possible to design an algorithm that detects (better: classifies to) one of multple targets. For example a Bag-of-Words classification, but those still depend on the number of targets. However if you have an appropriate image/object description you can drop most of the targets early and reduce computation to a few ones.

Comment: Also, multiple image scan won't be the bottleneck. It most likely will be the logic of your detector(s).

Comment: @Micka fixed the title. Yes, the primary goal is to detect (one of) multiple objects. I can probably live with the following logic - if one object is found, remove it from detection and repeat the process. But I am not sure it is so easy to remove.

Comment: @Miki how much time does it take to scan for a single image like 100x100 on 1920x1080 shot? With the speed of about 1m/s I need to read sign information at least four times, so every 25cm the object needs to be able to process the road information. I have only 250ms per image to process it.

Comment: you should first think about HOW to detect your objects at all. Typically it is a combination of bottom-up and top-down computation. Assuming that all objects can be computed with the same bottom-up information (e.g. edges and color) you only have to compute that bottom-up information once. But after all you should either learn computer vision yourself or hire an expert to solve that task.

Comment: @Micka it is catch22 - without knowing the algorithms I can not calculate the speed, without knowing the speed I can't learn the algorithms. That's why I am asking. Because the speed is the priority, I have the freedom to choose signs that will suit the algorithm, so any input about algorithms limitations and applicability to this specific case is welcome.

Comment: `without knowing the speed I can't learn the algorithms` why is that? You can capture images offline and try different algorithms, measuring speed offline. Obviously, if I had to plan and build an airport I couldn't do it because I have no idea about civil engineering. The kind of questions you are asking have some problems. You ask about speed but you don't know anything about computer vision, so you might not know that it's unclear whether there is a solution to your task at all (not concerning speed of the algorithm, just a solution)!

Comment: Basic bottom-up methods can be described by meaningful O(n) notation, like Filtering: O(n*k^2) where n is the number of pixels and k is the filter size. If the filter is separable, the algorithm can be optimized to O(2*n*k) which is much faster for typical resolutions and filter sizes. Filtering can be solved by fourier transformation which needs O(n*log(n)) (fast fourier transform) but after fourier transform, the actual filtering doesnt depend on k anymore, which makes it much faster for big filter kernels.

Comment: but filtering is a very basic method and different solutions lead to the very same (or very similar) result. That's not the case for complex methods like object detection, where different algorithms lead to different results (accuracy/robustness). Algorithmic complexity of those methods makes it hard to find significant predictions of speed complexity. For example, brute-force matching needs a quadratic number of object comparisons, but might be efficient enough for many real-time application (if few keypoints are used).

Comment: That could qualify as an answer. Is it possible to merge multiple different filters into one? `separable filter` - is that it?

Comment: I could also accept this information as an answer. Especially if it could be tied to my 1920x1080 source camera shot, 100 100x100 signs in the database, and 250ms to detect all signs conditions. What algorithms could work for that, and how the signs will be different from real life road signs for those algorithms.